# How to pass two or more parameters while calling a module in codeigniter HMVC (MX)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I'm using HMVC Modular Extension for CodeIgniter https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home .

call it inside your SITE view easily

```
Modules::run('modulename/controller/method')
```

We can pass single parameter like

```
Modules::run('modulename/controller/method',$parameter)
```

How can I pass two or more parameters through this?

Codeigniter version : 2.1.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass two or more variables as shown below

```
Modules::run('modulename/controller/method',$parameter1,$parameter2,$parameter3)
```

You can pass more parameters separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass params to the _construct

```
$modulo = array('programas'=>array('cxcxc','todo'));
$programas = Modules::load($modulo);
```